# Clause in SQL Natural Join

Tags: sql, join, oracle10g

```
SELECT * FROM TAB1 NATURAL JOIN TAB2
ON(CONDITION);
```

This query gives error.

```
SELECT * FROM TAB1 NATURAL JOIN TAB2
WHERE(CONDITION);
```

This query executed successfully.

So Why WHERE clause is used instead of ON clause in SQL Natural Join ?

Comment: It's best practice to avoid natural joins. Use an INNER JOIN with an ON condition.

Answer (score 3):

A `natural join` does not require a join condition because it is defined to implicitly join the two tables on the columns with the same name.

Therefore the `on ...` is invalid for `natural join`, [which is clearly documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55322):

> **Restriction on the ON condition Clause**
> You cannot specify this clause with a NATURAL outer join.

The `where` condition in your second query has nothing to do with the join. It's just a condition applied to the overall result.